# Java Jackson Json Array Serialization

Tags: java, arrays, json, serialization, jackson

I have a special case that I have been trying to serialize with Jackson. Here is a sample.

```
{
    "key1": [
        [
            10,
            11
        ],
        [
            12,
            13
        ]
    ],
    "key2": [
        [
            14,
            15
        ],
        [
            16,
            17
        ]
    ]
}
```

How can I make a model with decorators that will serialize this payload?

EDIT:

Assume there is a JSON file with the above contents. How can I make a POJO that can be used to serialize the above JSON like so with Jackson:

```
MyPOJO pojo = objectMapper.readValue(new File("above_json.json"), MyPOJO.class);
```

Here is a very simple example of what I am looking for:

JSON Input:

```
"Parameter":{
    "Name":"Parameter-Name",
    "Value":"Parameter-Value"
}
```

POJO to serialize above simple JSON:

```
public class Parameter {
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String name;
    @JsonProperty("Value")
    public String value; 
}
```

I am looking for a class, just like `Parameter` above that will serialize the example JSON that I provided originally above, rather than the simplified JSON.

Comment: *How can I make a model with decorators that will serialize this payload?* what do you mean ?? if your question is not clear, then we will be force to close this post. Make sure, you share enough data/code to understand what are you asking

Comment: Why is this a "special case"?

Comment: share more infomation

Comment: @shmosel special case means it is not something that seems straight forward to serialize if you just look at basic examples from the documentation.

Added info to the OP. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: @Ryan *it is not something that seems straight forward*, for me it is straight forward. Could you explain, how is it complex ?

Comment: A simplistic model might be `Map<String, List<List<Integer>>>`. Or `class MyPOJO { int[][] key1, key2; }`. It's not very clear what specifically you're looking for.

Comment: Okay, I added a clear and very simple example of what I am looking for. I am really just not sure how to translate the JSON that I have into a class like `Parameter` that I provided.

Comment: @Ryan Your JSON data and JSON input example are totally different.

Comment: @Ravi Yes that's the point. They are supposed to be different. If I was able to supply an example with identical or extremely similar JSON that worked for me, then I wouldn't need to ask this question. The point of the example was to show what I am looking for. All I want to do is translate my JSON into a POJO like in my simple example.

Comment: @Ryan Then your question is broad and needs to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assume there is a JSON file with the above contents. How can I make a POJO that can be used to serialize the above JSON like so with Jackson

This is very simple, you need to understand the data of your JSON. You have `key-value` and each value is Array of another Array. That is similar to

```
class POJO
{
     List<List<Integer>> key1;
     List<List<Integer>> key2; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed.